# C# excel range.FormulaArray not working

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, hp-uft

Here is my C# code to write ArrayFormula to certain cell in excel.
I am using UFT (Unified Functional Testing) which uses C# for custom code.

```
String sheetName = "xyz";
String wsMethodName = "abc";
int i = 2;
Excel.Application xlApp = null;
xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(srcFile,
                               0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                               true, false, 0, true, false, false);
worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[sheetName];
Excel.Range excelCell = (Excel.Range)worksheet.get_Range("B2", "B21");

foreach (Excel.Range c in excelCell)
    {
        //
        strAvgFormula = 
            "=AVERAGEIFS(" +
            "(OFFSET(\'" + sheetName + "\'!$A$1,2,2,COUNTA(\'" + sheetName + "\'!$A:$A)-2,1))," +
            "OFFSET(\'" + sheetName + "\'!$A$1,2,16382,COUNTA(\'" + sheetName + "\'!$A:$A)-2,1)," +
            "(MID(C" + i + ",1,(FIND(\"-\",C" + i + "))-2))," +
            "OFFSET(\'" + sheetName + "\'!$A$1,2,16383,COUNTA(\'" + sheetName + "\'!$A:$A)-2,1)," +
            "(MID(C" + i + ",(FIND(\"-\",C" + i + ")+1),(FIND(\"/\",C" + i + "))-(FIND(\"-\",C" + i + ")+1))))";
        this.CodeActivity16.Report("strAvgFormula",strAvgFormula);

        //
        strMaxFormula = 
            "=MAX(" +
            "IF((OFFSET(\'" + sheetName + "\'!$A$1,2,16382,COUNTA(\'" + sheetName + "\'!$A:$A)-2,1)=MID(C" + i + ",1,(FIND(\"-\",C" + i + "))-2))*" +
            "(OFFSET(\'" + sheetName + "\'!$A$1,2,16383,COUNTA(\'" + sheetName + "\'!$A:$A)-2,1)=MID(C" + i + ",(FIND(\"-\",C" + i + ")+2)," +
            "(FIND(\"/\",C" + i + "))-(FIND(\"-\",C" + i + ")+2)))," +
            "OFFSET(\'" + sheetName + "\'!$A$1,2,2,COUNTA(\'" + sheetName + "\'!$A:$A)-2,1)))";
        this.CodeActivity16.Report("strMaxFormula",strMaxFormula);
        if (c.Value2.ToString() == wsMethodName)
            {
                newExcelCell = (Excel.Range)worksheet.get_Range("F" + i, "F" + i);
                newExcelCell.Clear();
                newExcelCell.FormulaArray = strAvgFormula;  //Failing @ this line, error is mentioned below
                //newExcelCell.Value = strAvgFormula;
                newExcelCell = (Excel.Range)worksheet.get_Range("G" + i, "G" + i);
                newExcelCell.Clear();
                newExcelCell.FormulaArray = strMaxFormula;
                //newExcelCell.Value = strMaxFormula;
                break;
            }
            i ++;
    }
wb.Save();
xlApp.Workbooks.Close();
xlApp.Quit();

releaseObject(newExcelCell);
releaseObject(excelCell);
releaseObject(worksheet);
releaseObject(wb);
releaseObject(xlApp);  

private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            CodeActivity16.Report("Error","Unable to release the Object " +     ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Now, If I copy the same formula from printed output result and paste it in my desired cell, it is working fine.
Escape characters are doing their job properly.
If I change **newExcelCell.FormulaArray** to **newExcelCell.Value**, than it is writing to excel but it works as normal formula and not the ArrayFormula (like we do Ctrl + Shift + Enter).

Here is the error that I am getting from result file:
The formula you typed contains an error. Try one of the following:
• Make sure you've included all parentheses and required arguments.
• To get assistance with using a function, click Function Wizard on the Formulas tab (in the Function Library group).
• If you include a reference to another sheet or workbook, verify that the reference is correct.
• If you are not trying to enter a formula, avoid using an equal sign (=) or minus sign (-), or precede it with a single quotation mark ( ' ).
• For more information about common formula problems, click Help.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the formula for **strAvgFormula** that I am trying to write.

```
"=AVERAGEIFS(" +
"(OFFSET('1'!$A$1,2,2,COUNTA('1'!$A:$A)-2,1))," +
"OFFSET('1'!$A$1,2,16382,COUNTA('1'!$A:$A)-2,1),(MID(C2,1,(FIND("-",C2))-2))," +
"OFFSET('1'!$A$1,2,16383,COUNTA('1'!$A:$A)-2,1),(MID(C2,(FIND("-",C2)+1),(FIND("/",C2))-(FIND("-",C2)+1))))"
```

Formula for **strMaxFormula** is working fine.

Comment: have you stepped thru / debugged the code..? the error message is telling you exactly what is wrong and or things to try to correct it.. have you tried commenting out the formula to narrow down which one of the 2 is incorrect?

Comment: @DJKRAZE, I stepped thru, and I know where it is failing (I mentioned in my code), now if I'll put 2nd formula 1st, than that won't work. Formula is working fine if I put it manually.

Comment: it's failing on this line `newExcelCell.FormulaArray = strAvgFormula` strAvgFormula is that an Array or a string.. this seems to be the issue.. can that be casted `ToArray()`

Comment: @DJKRAZE, `strAvgFormula` is a string which is holding my formula which I want to put in Excel cell.

Comment: my question is is newExcelCell.FormulaArray expect a `string or a string[] array`

Comment: @DJKRAZE, `newExcelCell.FormulaArray` expects a string only. And I've just checked, seems like `strMaxFormula` is working fine. Something is  wrong with `strAvgFormula`. But I am not getting it, it is working fine if I put that manually.

Comment: can you display manually what you are entering so that we can get a better understanding.. if it works manually fine.. I am still thinking that one of your parameters are off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I got the workaround for this issue.

It turned out (this is what I feel) that either the Excel is not accepting the formula from the string **strAvgFormula** or it get messed up because of cell reference using **Offset**.

I've to use direct cell reference.

Here is my working formula:

```
int lastUsedRowDiffSheet = worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell,Type.Missing).Row;
strAvgFormula =
            "=AVERAGEIFS('" + sheetName + "\'!C" + iRowCount + ":C" + lastUsedRowDiffSheet + ","
            + "'" + sheetName + "'!XFC" + iRowCount + ":XFC" + lastUsedRowDiffSheet + ","
            + "MID(C" + i + ",1,(FIND(\"-\",C" + i + "))-2),"
            + "'" + sheetName + "\'!XFD" + iRowCount + ":XFD" + lastUsedRowDiffSheet + ","
            + "(MID(C" + i + ",(FIND(\"-\",C" + i + ")+1),(FIND(\"/\",C" + i + "))-(FIND(\"-\",C" + i + ")+1))))";
```

Answer (score 1):

> [The FormulaArray property also has a character limit of 255.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-formulaarray-property-excel)

A workaround can be to set it to less than 256 characters, and replace part of it. For example:

```
range.FormulaArray = "={1,2,3}";
range.Replace("}", ",4,5,6}", XlLookAt.xlPart);
```

https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/working-with-range-formulaarray-in-vba/

http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/01/10/entering-long-array-formulas-in-vba/